# Combine two pipe commands into a single command

Tags: linux, grep, pipe, echo

I have theses two codes and i want to merge/combine them into a single one :

```
rostopic echo /cmd_vel | grep -A 3 angular | grep -v x | grep -v y | cut -d : -f 2

rostopic echo /cmd_vel | grep -A 1 linear | grep -v linear | cut -d : -f 2
```

how to do that?

Comment: please edit your question and add sample output for `rostopic echo /cmd_vel`.

Comment: please dont pay attention to `rostopic echo /cmd_vel`, it's just an echo from [ROS](https://www.ros.org/). An OS made from Linux.
and `rostopic echo /cmd_vel` echoing on terminal the velocity of my robot.

Comment: it doesn't really matter what the command is.  what is needed is sample output.

Comment: It would be helpful to see an example of the output *without* any manipulation, i.e., the raw *output*

Comment: All these comments with questions and suggestions indicate that we want you to tell us what you want. **Please explain** (otherwise we can only guess and might suggest things that are very different from what you want).

Comment: seems to be documented at [Using rostopic echo](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics#Using_rostopic_echo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```c
rostopic echo /cmd_vel | awk -F: '
         /angular/ { m = "z" ; next};   # we want z from angular
         /linear/  { m = "x" ; next};   # and x from linear
         { 
           gsub(/ /,"",$1);    # strip spaces from $1

           if ($1 == m) {      
             gsub(/ /,"",$2);  # strip spaces from $2
             print $2;         
             m = ""            # reset m so it doesnt match anything
           } 
         }'
```

This assumes that the output of `rostopic echo /cmd_vel` is the same as described in [Using rostopic echo](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics#Using_rostopic_echo), e.g.:

```
linear:
  x: 2.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
---
```

The output of the awk script with that input would be:

```
2.0
0.0
```

i.e. the 2nd field of the first line after "linear", and the 2nd field of the line which **doesn't** contain x or y (i.e. must be z) after "angular".

---

Here's a slightly simpler version of the same script.  By setting the field separator to "one-or-more whitespace characters optionally preceded by a colon character" (with `-F':?[[:space:]]+'`) and taking into account that this change will affect the numbering of the fields, we don't need to use `gsub()`:

```c
rostopic echo /cmd_vel | 
  awk -F':?[[:space:]]+' '
      /angular/ { m = "z" ; next};
      /linear/  { m = "x" ; next};
      $2 && $2 == m { print $3 ; m = ""}'
```

Comment: thank you, correct answer.

Comment: There's a reason why we ask for sample input.   Even better would be to have sample input AND know exactly what you're trying to do because I very strongly suspect that I've just solved your [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) instead of the underlying problem you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: you are right sir, i will make sure to explain every thing with details next time. much appreciated.

Comment: please can you modify the code so it can run in a bash file (.sh)?

Comment: huh?  it was written so that it could function as-is in a shell script.   All you need to do is save it to a file, add `#!/bin/bash` as the first line, and make it executable with `chmod +x` - which is exactly how i wrote it on my system before copy-pasting the pipeline to here.

Comment: well, i did all that already but i still getting this error :

/pipe.sh: line 3: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
./pipe.sh: line 15: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: You must have mis-typed something. the script works.  I even tested it again by copy-pasting it from this answer back into another bash script and ran it.  it works.

Comment: nope, i didn't misstype, just copy+paste the whole code. 
Here a screenshot of my output after the copy paste https://ibb.co/WgBhbrL

Comment: check it again.  the script works.  try pasting your copy of the script into https://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1):

With `tee` and an output process substitution:

```bsh
rostopic echo /cmd_vel \
| tee >(grep -A 3 angular | grep -v x | grep -v y | cut -d : -f 2) \
| grep -A 1 linear | grep -v linear | cut -d : -f 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [another great answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/652786/409852), you can do it somewhat in "parallel" but using `paste`:

```bsh
paste <(rostopic echo /cmd_vel | grep -A 3 angular | grep -v x | grep -v y | cut -d : -f 2) <(rostopic echo /cmd_vel | grep -A 1 linear | grep -v linear | cut -d : -f 2)
```

It doesn't accept piped input like `tee` does but it *is* faster.